# Typescript/Apollo: access property from in memory cache

Tags: typescript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client and am learning Typescript. I have a `Mutation` component with this update prop:

```
(cache, { data: { createTask } }) => {
    const allTasks = cache.readQuery({ query: ALL_TASKS }).allTasks;
}
```

I get two compilation errors:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
Property 'allTasks' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I understand the general idea. `readQuery` might return `null` (which is it self confusing because the docs lead me to believe that an error is thrown when no results are found (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#readquery).

How can I get the compiler to let me read the property `allTasks` from the result of `readQuery`?

Also, FYI I tried running `console.log(cache.readQuery({ query: ALL_TASKS }))` and confirmed that there is indeed valid data there with a property called.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`readQuery` accepts a type argument for the type of the result; you can see this [in the source code](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/d185f41fb13eeaae38aa66582d3b2ea1ebf48d43/packages/apollo-client/src/ApolloClient.ts#L301) or by jumping to the declaration of `readQuery` in your IDE.  Thus, you can do:

```
interface AllTasksResult {
  allTasks: any;  // TODO: Put correct type here
}
// ...
const allTasks = cache.readQuery<AllTasksResult>({ query: ALL_TASKS })!.allTasks;
```

About the `null`: Consider filing a bug for the inconsistency between the type declarations and the documentation.  For now, the exclamation mark claims that you know the preceding expression (the return value of `readQuery`) won't be null or undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copy/pasted that into my code and am still getting `Object is possibly 'null'.`

Comment: Yes, I suppose you need to use a non-null assertion unless/until the type declarations are fixed.  Updated the answer.